# Conditionality on a random variable

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let $Y$ and $Z$ be the random variables.$Y$ is defined as

$Y=Z+Z+Z+Z+.........(N times)$ where N is Poisson distributed. How to find the CDF of $Y$?

I'm thinking like this, but i'm not sure whether this correct or not.
$$\
 F_\mathcal{Y}(y)  =  \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} P_\mathcal{N}(n) F_\mathcal{Y}(y|N)$$

I'm confused in calculating  $F_\mathcal{Y}(y|N)$.

my work is here:

suppose if N=1 , then $Y=Z \Longrightarrow F_\mathcal{Y}(y|N=1)=F_z(y)$

if N=2 , then $Y=Z+Z=2Z \Longrightarrow F_\mathcal{Y}(y|N=2)=2F_z(y)$

if N=3 , then $Y=Z+Z+Z=3Z \Longrightarrow F_\mathcal{Y}(y|N=3)=3F_z(y)$

Therefore $ F_\mathcal{Y}(y|N)=NF_z(y)$.

$$\
 F_\mathcal{Y}(y)  =  \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{(\lambda A)^n}{n!} e^{-\lambda A}  (nF_z(y))$$.

Is it correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right so far. 
\begin{align}
F_y(y|N=n) &= P(Y \leq y | N=n) \\
&= P(n*Z \leq y) \\
&= P(Z \leq y/n) \\
&= F_z(y/n)
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you. This makes sense to me. there is an extension to this problem which is :  Let $Z_1,Z_2,Z_3,.....Z_N$ are the independent random variables which has the same distribution as Z. Similarly here N is Poisson distributed.and $ Y= Z_1+Z_2+Z_3+ ...$.(how many random variables you need to add depends on N) . So, what should be the $ F_Y(y|N)$?

Comment: May be is it looks like this:  \begin{eqnarray*}   
  F_Y(y|N=n) & = & P(Y\leq y|N=n) \\
             & = & P(Z_1+Z_2+Z_3+...Z_n \leq y) \\
                \end{eqnarray*}

Comment: For this extension, we need to evaluate $P(Z_1+Z_2+...+Z_n \leq y)$. Given that $Z_i$s are IID, the distribution of the sum of IID RVs will be convolution of the individual distributions (in this case distribution of $Z$).

Comment: i also thought like that, But i remember that the density is the convolution of the IID Rvs not the distribution.

Comment: I was about to edit my comment for that. If the RVs have continuous distribution, you can calculate pdf and obtain cdf through integration.

Comment: I found this one : $Z=X+Y$ then $F_Z(z)=F_X(z)*dF_Y(z) $. So, based on that  \begin{eqnarray*}   
  F_Y(y|N=n) & = & F_Z(y)*dF_Z(y)*dF_Z(y)*....
                \end{eqnarray*}  So, I found $  F_Y(y) $ like this
  
  \begin{eqnarray*}   
  F_Y(y) & = &  \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{(\lambda A)^n}{n!} e^{-\lambda A} \left\lbrace F_Z(y)*dF_Z(y)*dF_Z(y)*....\right\rbrace 
                \end{eqnarray*}
                
                Is there any better way to represent this equation ,may be by using recursion.thank you for your time. you really helped me a lot.

Comment: I cant think of any unless there is a short form to denote n-times convolution.